# Optimal JVM settings for IntelliJ 15 CE

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea, jvm

IntelliJ comes with some default settings for JVM(Java 8) which are far beyond from optimal. I experience some unexpected freezes, relatively high CPU usage, etc.

Unfortunately, I have no experience in tuning JVM, so I would like to ask a community to suggest best JVM settings for Mac machine that has i7 CPU + 16GB of RAM to achieve the most responsive and low CPU usage experience in IntelliJ 15 CE (Golang plugin) assuming that I am not running lots of apps in parallel, just couple office apps for communication needs.

Settings can be configured here:
~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC15/idea.vmoptions

My current config is:

```
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
-XX:NewRatio=3
-Xss16m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

I am not sure most of these options make much sense, I expect some of them are already obsolete and enabled by default. However, with this config CPU usage dropped dramatically, as well as IDE is much more responsive, but short freezes are still noticeable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to play around with the values provided by JetBrains unless you know what you are doing.

If you do experience issues with the IDE being slow, you can follow [Reporting performance problems tutorial](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827577-Reporting-performance-problems) to help Jetbrains help you.

And as a final thought, I have a Ubuntu 15.10, IDEA 15, Go plugin (latest nightly, but stable is fine as well) with 3000+ Go package in my GOPATH and I don't have any freezes and such so I would guess it's something that's better handled by JetBrains rather than tweaking the JVM values :)

Comment: Woow, unexpected people.
Well, I needed to change those parameters. Otherwise it was not nice experience. I was using IntelliJ 14 + golang plugin, there were no freezes, but IDE was relatively slow and CPU was hot. With intellij 15 things got a little worse, freezes were added.

I actually followed zolotov suggestion to tune these parameters, it helped.

Comment: Sure, but then if you do have a problem with them, I'd rather use the method described in the reporting performance problems to help them understand where the performance leaks happen.

Also, the memory settings you have seems to be a bit low, see the first link below.

Additionally, maybe these will help you further:
- http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2015/11/1-and-the-only-one-to-customize-intellij-idea-memory-settings/
- https://gist.github.com/P7h/4388881

Comment: Additionally, you could also look into the zero-latency typing option present in IDEA 15: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/08/experimental-zero-latency-typing-in-intellij-idea-15-eap/ (I have it enabled by default)

Comment: Thanks of the URLs, it helped. However, this is why I created this topic - I have no good idea how to tune these parameters. Default parameters are too small.
Just take a look at these:

    -Xms128m
    -Xmx750m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=350m
    -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
    -XX:+UseCompressedOops